# Sorting by hibernate with special arrangement

Tags: hibernate

I am now facing a problem about Sorting the result getting from DB.
I want to sort by ASC but I want to make an exception , "OTHERS". So the selection "Others" will be at last of the selection. How can i implement this?
So, the ComboBox List will like this :

```
AA
BB
CC
DD
......
......
XX
YY
ZZ
Others
```

Code i tried:

```
public List<Testing> findAll() {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Testing.class);
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("TestingString"));
    return (List<Testing>) criteria.list();
}
```

By using this coding, "Others" will between "OO" and "PP". It is a bad way to show the selection "Others".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No straightforward way with Hibernate, but you can totally do that in your code. I think of 2 ways:

1. Do not keep Others in database. Retrieve the sorted list from DB and then add Others to the last of the list manually in your java code.
2. Keep Others in DB, retrieve all as per normal without even sorting and then call Collections.sort(resultList, comparator) where comparator is your custom comparator in which it compares strings alphabetically but always put Others as biggest value. That will return list you want.

Comment: i followed your first solutions, it works great, Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

On hibernate you can define a @Formula annotated field where the value is SQL representation of the order. Then use the @Formula annotated field in your sort.

The expression could be

```
CASE columnName
   WHEN 'Other' THEN 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
   ELSE columnName
END
```